# multiple field aggregation on documents with multiple elements gives unexpected result

Tags: elasticsearch

I have documents with the following structure (very much simplified for the example):

```
"documents": [
    {
        "name": "Document 1",
        "collections" : [
            {
                "id": 30,
                "title" : "Research"
            },
            {
                "id": 45,
                "title" : "Events"
            },
            {
                "id" : 52,
                "title" : "International"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "name": "Document 2",
        "collections" : [
            {
                "id": 45,
                "title" : "Events"
            },
            {
                "id" : 63,
                "title" : "Development"
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

I want an aggregation of the collection. It works fine when I do it like this:

```
    "aggs": {
        "collections": {
            "terms": {
                "field": "collections.title",
                "size": 30
            }
        }
    }
```

I get a nice result as expected:

```
    "aggregations" : {
        "collections" : {
            "doc_count_error_upper_bound" : 0,
            "sum_other_doc_count" : 0,
            "buckets" : [
                {
                    "key" : "Research",
                    "doc_count" : 18
                },
                {
                    "key" : "Events",
                    "doc_count" : 14
                },
                {
                    "key" : "International",
                    "doc_count" : 13
                },
                {
                    "key" : "Development",
                    "doc_count" : 8
                }
            ]
        }
    }
```

However, I want the id included as well. So I tried this:

```
    "aggs": {
        "collections": {
            "terms": {
                "field": "collections.title",
                "size": 30
            }
        },
        "aggs": {
            "id": {
                "terms": {
                    "field": "collections.id",
                    "size": 1
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

This is the result:

```
    "aggregations" : {
        "collections" : {
            "doc_count_error_upper_bound" : 0,
            "sum_other_doc_count" : 0,
            "buckets" : [
                {
                    "key" : "Research",
                    "doc_count" : 18,
                    "id" : {
                        "doc_count_error_upper_bound" : 0,
                        "sum_other_doc_count" : 0,
                        "buckets" : [
                            {
                                "key" : "30",
                                "doc_count" : 1
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                },
                {
                    "key" : "Events",
                    "doc_count" : 14,
                    "id" : {
                        "doc_count_error_upper_bound" : 0,
                        "sum_other_doc_count" : 0,
                        "buckets" : [
                            {
                                "key" : "45",
                                "doc_count" : 1
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                },
                {
                    "key" : "International",
                    "doc_count" : 13,
                    "id" : {
                        "doc_count_error_upper_bound" : 0,
                        "sum_other_doc_count" : 0,
                        "buckets" : [
                            {
                                "key" : "52",
                                "doc_count" : 1
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                },
                {
                    "key" : "Development",
                    "doc_count" : 8,
                    "id" : {
                        "doc_count_error_upper_bound" : 0,
                        "sum_other_doc_count" : 0,
                        "buckets" : [
                            {
                                "key" : "45",
                                "doc_count" : 1
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    }
```

At glance it looks good. But at a closer look the at the last element with Development (scroll down). The id should be 63, but is 45.
I have vague idea why this is, but I cannot find a solution for it. I also tried the multi_terms, but it gives a similar result. I think the issue has to do with the fact there are multiple collections within the document.
Does anyone know the correct solution to solve this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason is in an object type mapping there is no relation between "title" and "id" , everything is flatenned by Elasticsearch under the hood, so:

```
"collections" : [
            {
                "id": 30,
                "title" : "Research"
            },
            {
                "id": 45,
                "title" : "Events"
            },
            {
                "id" : 52,
                "title" : "International"
            }
        ]
```

Becomes:

```
"collections.id": [30,45,52],
"collections.title": [Research, Events, International]
```

Elasticsearch doesn't know id 30 belongs to Research, or id 45 to Events.

You must use "nested" type to keep the relation between nested properties.
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/nested.html

**Solution: Use nested field type**

**Mappings**

```
PUT test_nestedaggs
{
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "name": {
        "type": "text"
      },
      "collections": {
        "type": "nested",
        "properties": {
          "title": {
            "type": "keyword"
          },
          "id": {
            "type": "keyword"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**Documents**

```
POST test_nestedaggs/_doc
{
  "name": "Document 1",
  "collections": [
    {
      "id": 30,
      "title": "Research"
    },
    {
      "id": 45,
      "title": "Events"
    },
    {
      "id": 52,
      "title": "International"
    }
  ]
}
    
POST test_nestedaggs/_doc
{
  "name": "Document 2",
  "collections": [
    {
      "id": 45,
      "title": "Events"
    },
    {
      "id": 63,
      "title": "Development"
    }
  ]
}
```

**Query**

```
POST test_nestedaggs/_search?size=0
{
  "aggs": {
    "nested_collections": {
      "nested": {
        "path": "collections"
      },
      "aggs": {
        "collections": {
          "terms": {
            "field": "collections.title"
          },
          "aggs": {
            "ids": {
              "terms": {
                "field": "collections.id"
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**Results**

```
{
  "took": 1,
  "timed_out": false,
  "_shards": {
    "total": 1,
    "successful": 1,
    "skipped": 0,
    "failed": 0
  },
  "hits": {
    "total": {
      "value": 2,
      "relation": "eq"
    },
    "max_score": null,
    "hits": []
  },
  "aggregations": {
    "nested_collections": {
      "doc_count": 5,
      "collections": {
        "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 0,
        "sum_other_doc_count": 0,
        "buckets": [
          {
            "key": "Events",
            "doc_count": 2,
            "ids": {
              "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 0,
              "sum_other_doc_count": 0,
              "buckets": [
                {
                  "key": "45",
                  "doc_count": 2
                }
              ]
            }
          },
          {
            "key": "Development",
            "doc_count": 1,
            "ids": {
              "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 0,
              "sum_other_doc_count": 0,
              "buckets": [
                {
                  "key": "63",
                  "doc_count": 1
                }
              ]
            }
          },
          {
            "key": "International",
            "doc_count": 1,
            "ids": {
              "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 0,
              "sum_other_doc_count": 0,
              "buckets": [
                {
                  "key": "52",
                  "doc_count": 1
                }
              ]
            }
          },
          {
            "key": "Research",
            "doc_count": 1,
            "ids": {
              "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 0,
              "sum_other_doc_count": 0,
              "buckets": [
                {
                  "key": "30",
                  "doc_count": 1
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  }
}
```

You can read an article I wrote about that for details:

https://opster.com/guides/elasticsearch/data-architecture/elasticsearch-nested-field-object-field/

*NOTE: If the number of child documents is too big and you are doing a lot of updates, consider changing the data model because each child document is an independent document in the index, and on each update on a child document the whole structure will reindex and that may affect the performance, there are also limits in the maximum of nested documents you can add. If the number is small like the example then it's fine.*

Comment: Super, works perfect! Thanks for your eleborate example. 
Sorry for my late reply but couldn't make the change to the mappings until today.

Comment: Thats nice! , remember to mark this as the right answer